woocommerce, add free sample button on product page
want to add a secondary button on product page with the name "free sample". it will work just like the add to cart button but with price and quantity override.
when somebody click on  "free sample" it will add 1 product with $1 price to the cart.
i tried this example but didn't succeed (https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-order-free-sample-single-product-page/)
thanks in advance

What do you mean by "didn't succeed"? Help people to help you.

bcoz its only for one particular product, for each product you need to add code multiple time which is not feasible.

You've misread or badly implemented some of the code in the article, because if you

Created the free sample product
Added the provided code to your theme's functions.php file, changing "123" to the ID of the free sample product you created earlier it should work for all your products


@Chris, as i said in my first comment, its not feasible, i'm sure their is batter way to do it, its just that i'm not able to find/ get it. thats why i came here.

You also said in your first comment that you'd have to do it multiple times, which is how I knew you'd misnderstood how it works.

I've tested the code in the article here and it works as intended: https://southwalesantiques.co.uk/
